# Angular Two dimensional ng model

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a time table for class using html table,Each  tag contains one subject, the problem is for each cell i need to define unique ng model. the below code works fine for first  ,in all  tags from next , ng-model have same value. Here is my code

```
    <tr ng-repeat="day in days track by $index">
        <td>
         <input ng-disabled="true" class="form-control" ng-model="weekdays[$index]"></td><td ng-repeat="period in periods track by $index"><input type="text"
        ng-model="timetable.subject[[$parent.$index][$index]]"
        name="name"
        uib-typeahead="onesectionsubject as onesectionsubject.subjectMaster.subjectName+'/'+onesectionsubject.subjectTeacher.firstName for onesectionsubject in onesectionsubjects | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8"
        class="form-control" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9 ]*"
        uib-tooltip="Enter valid subject name"
        tooltip-enable="form.name.$invalid" autocomplete="off">
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Do you want to load a different model for every option in the table?

Comment: i am having ng repeat in <tr> and <td> i am trying to achieve a time table like structure thus require unique ng model for  each cell in table

Comment: Is this possible or not??

Comment: Hi, sorry, I wasn't around, I don't think so, but anyways, you could also open an issue at: https://github.com/angular/angular.js -  and see if someone can come up with a similar solution.